# HTML Submit button hide on press

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my web application, I want to hide the submit button when the user clicks it.

Normally that option wasn't there earlier and when clicking the submit button, the request was submitted.

Then I add this code to hide the submit button on click

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit Request" class="btn btn-success" onClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending...'; submitForm(); return false;" />
```

Now the issue is it's hidden but the request has not been submitted to the controller.

Comment: write your form submit code inside `submitForm()` function of `javascript`

Comment: it's strange because disable = true doesn't hide anything so there's some logic you are doing in submitForm or you are missing some details

Comment: can you also type here the code `submitForm()`

Comment: @Aristos ``@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "AppRequests", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to run some Javascript against this code? If so you could use
this for html:

```
<form id="my-form" action="/whatever action">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Request" id="btn-show" 
      class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var button = document.getElementById('btn-show')
    button.addEventListener('click',hideshow);

    function hideshow() {
       document.getElementById('btn-show').style.display = 'block'; 
        this.style.display = 'none'
       document.getElementById("my-form").submit();
       document.getElementById('btn-show').disabled=true; 
       document.getElementById('btn-show').value='Sending...';
       return false
    }   
</script>
```

look at the codepen for how you could fit this into your project: https://codepen.io/bolti95/pen/qBpxgOQ